# Apache force ssl to specific URL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

how can I configure apache httpd 2.x to force ssl when a certain URL is called ? For instance, let http://www.mycompany.com be plain-text by default, except when a user opens **http**://www.mycompany.com/secure (and anything below) it forces **https**://www.mycompany.com/secure.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/secure(.*) https://www.mycompany.com/secure$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable `mod_rewrite` and add the following to your Apache config:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} secure 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mycompany.com/secure/$1 [R,L]
```